# include with nested round brackets

Tags: php

What does the code below means in PHP7:

`(require __DIR__ . '/routes.php')($app);`

And how to convert it to non-Uniform syntax?

*routes.php content*:

````
use Slim\App;

return function (App $app) {
    // empty
};```
````

Comment: What does `routes.php` contain?

Comment: <?php

use Slim\App;

return function (App $app) {
    // empty
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`require`](http://php.net/require)/[`include`](http://php.net/include)/[`eval`](http://php.net/eval) behave like expressions, specifically when the invoked code/file returns something. In this case the return value is used as a function expression. It's equivalent to:

```
$return = (require "file.php");
${NULL} = $return($app);
```